# OpenGL ES 2.0 projecting point

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to use

> GLU.gluProject();

. Function wants viewport (*int [ ]* ) parameter. I assume that the *int* array contains x,y,width,height, which were set by:

> GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

am I correct?

Also origin point in OpenGL is in the left bottom corner? So when you have detected touch on android device for ex. at x = 255, y = 255 you have to recalculate it? (I'm computing ray start and end point ;) )

Comment: The origin depends on many many things. For simplest of cases drawing in 2D you usually use glOrtho which contains parameters top, bottom, left and right which can be set so that top left is the origin (0,0). The default (not setting anything) I believe the origin is in centre and left is -1, right is 1, top is 1 and bottom is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 8th parameter of `GLU.gluProject()`, which is named `view` in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29), is an array containing x, y, width, height of the viewport:

> view | the current view, {x, y, width, height}

The origin of window coordinates in OpenGL is in the bottom-left corner of the window.

For the coordinates you use for drawing, you can apply your own transformations, so it's your choice what coordinate system you want to use. Your vertex shader needs to apply transformations to transform your input coordinates into normalized device coordinates (NDC), which have range [-1.0, 1.0] from left to right and from bottom to top.

Comment: so, let's say touch input (x = 200, y = 350) where screen width is 400 and height is 700, you have to recalculate into [-1, 1] range to get them into correct form? To be more specific I got camera at vec3(0,0,-3), looking at vec3(0,0,0) with no other world transforms, and ortho projection (left -1, right 1, bottom -1, top 1)